# In old google chrome gwt form design shows properly. but chrome new version 65.0.3325.162 not supported

Tags: java, css, gwt, flextable

We have designed our forms using flextable which work proper up to 64 version of google chorme. bt in google chrome new version 65.0.3325.162 not display properly.

Each form fields are added using setwidget method of flextable

```
            InlineLabel lbl=new InlineLabel(formfields[j][i].getLabel());
            **setWidget**(j, k, lbl);
            Widget widg=formfields[j][i].getWidget();
            **setWidget**(j, k+1, widg);
```

**New version look for google chrome. not working properly. :(**

[image]

**[old version look for google chrome.]**

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details of the code? `getWidget()` and such, since Chrome 65 seems to be just fine with a normal FlexTable, InlineLabel. Or, share the old working vs new broken DOM structure, if you think that FlexTable is building the wrong content now. http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFlexTable

Comment: Sample with InlineLabel https://viola.colinalworth.com/proj/54177c9456d1c4f777d17dc6600251cd/project/client/SampleEntryPoint.java

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using rowspan,colspan property of flextable properly.  :)